# Creating a single PDF file from multiple templates with iText

Tags: java, spring, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have the following piece of code that would open a PDF template, fill the AcroFields with data from the `Receipt` object and output to the browser. It works perfect with one instance of my Receipt but now I one to repeat the process with a List of Receipts so that I can produce a single PDF file concatenating the pdf stamper instances.

This is my code right now:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");

PdfReader pdfTemplate = new PdfReader ("/receipt-template.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfTemplate, response.getOutputStream());
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

// fill the fields as
form.setField("number", recipt.getNumber().toString());

// ...
stamper.close();
pdfTemplate.close();
```

I would like to do something like:

```
pdf = new pdf
foreach receipt in receiptsList
    partial = fillReceiptTemplate (receipt)
    pdf.append (partial)
output pdf
```

Is it possible? I've read in some forums that I should use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` but I have no clue how, in other places says that's not possible to concatenate the whole pdf document so I should add pages instead..

Comment: Hello there.  I have a problem that I believe is very similar, detailed here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/239095/78820 .  Does this seem like a related situation?  Do you have any insight now that you have been successful yourself?  It's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me summarize what the documentation says about your question:

1. If the final document needs to be interactive, you have a problem. If you read ISO-32000-1, you'll find out that a PDF document can contain only one form. A single field can correspond with multiple widget annotations, but it can only have *one* value. For instance: if you have a form with the field *name*, and you concatenate the same form more than once (using `PdfCopyFields`), then all the pages containing a widget annotation corresponding with the field *name* will show the same name. You can't have one page where the *name* field shows *Bruno* and another field where the *name* field shows *Joaquin*. This is explained in section 6.4.3 of [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book, where example [ConcatenateForms1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=126) results in multiple widgets for the same field, and [ConcatenateForms2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=127) renames the fields before concatenating the forms.
2. In your case, you don't have that problem. You flatten the form using the line `stamper.setFormFlattening(true);` you can concatenate the results as shown in section 6.4.2 of [chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book, where [DataSheets1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=124) uses `PdfCopy` resulting in a huge file size, and [DataSheets2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=125) uses `PdfSmartCopy` results in a PDF with a more acceptable size.

The difference between 'final results needs to remain a form' and 'final result can be flattened' may explain why you're getting mixed information on different forums.

Note that the `DataSheets` examples don't store the individual files on disk. Instead the bytes are kept in memory using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` of which the `toByteArray()` is used to construct the `PdfReader` instance.

Comment: Perfect answer, finally I used PdfSmartCopy succesfully bypassing the content to the reader with a ByteArrayOutputStream